# Bootstrap: Pictures gets aligned to the left page side when using Carousel

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I use Bootstrap's Carousel component. It is placed within grid system with only one column (out of 12), which spans the whole page. However, pictures embedded within Carousel get aligned to the left page side, and I want them to be centered.

I copied and pasted Basic template from Get Bootstrap website, inserted grid system with only one column, and placed the Carousel within it, but the pictures always got left aligned.

Bootstrap is 3.3.7, Ubuntu 16.04 LTS Desktop, the latest Mozilla Firefox, fresh Apache and MySQL.

The relevant code follows.

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-12">
    <div id="carousel-example-generic" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
      <!-- Indicators -->
      <ol class="carousel-indicators">
        <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
        <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="1"></li>
        <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="2"></li>
      </ol>
      <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
      <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
        <div class="item active">
          <img src="img/pic0.jpg" alt="Picture 0">
          <div class="carousel-caption">
            This is the Picture 0
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
          <img src="img/pic1.jpg" alt="Picture 1">
          <div class="carousel-caption">
            This is the Picture 1
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
          <img src="img/pic2.jpg" alt="Picture 2">
          <div class="carousel-caption">
            This is the Picture 2
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <!-- Controls -->
      <!-- Default code from Get Bootstrap website -->
```

Answer (score 0):

This problem was due to the size of the image.

If you make 100% width of the image then this problem will be solved, So use the 1st method for this.

If you do not want to change the width of the image.And if you want to bring the image in center then use the 2nd method.

**Method 1:-**
Add this style in your internal/external stylesheet

```
.carousel-inner > .item > img, .carousel-inner > .item > a > img {
    width: 100%;
}
```

**Method 2:-**
Add this style in your internal/external stylesheet

```
.carousel-inner > .item > img, .carousel-inner > .item > a > img {
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Comment: The Method 2 works excellent for me, and I think I shall use it. Thank you :)

Comment: Your Welcome stameni, Please Upvote and Check it to write answer.